# How to get embedded image data from quill delta?

Tags: json, quill

I am considering to store quill JSON content on database,except embedded image,I will store image seperately on filesystem.So when I want to extraxt image from quill delta I see that no consistent JSON schema exist.I have this JSON when I have an image base64 encoded:

```
{
"ops": [{
    "insert": "some text here\n"
}, {
    "insert": {
        "image": "data:image/png;base64,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"
    }
}, {
    "insert": "\n"
}]
```

}

As you see, "insert" is not uniform,it can be either String or an object.That makes it impossible for me to deserialize it into to a (Java) Object.

So what is the way to extract the "image" here? Brtual String manipulation? Or am I missing something in this picture?

Answer (score 0):

you should try to send without json format it will help you. the thing is mattering with you is json is not able to send all the data which is require So for that what i had done is i have simply bind data into array format using javascript then send it as simple string using post data then using `$_POST`variable get that string